# How to make textbox work like drop-down

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to bind values from database to a text box and it should work just like drop down. I should be able to type in the values in the text box, populate matching keyword same time and also i should get a scroll bar while entering values.

Can you help me, how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the ajax toolkit's auto complete extender or some other jQuery plugin. Here is how you can use the `ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender`. Refer [here](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) for more options. Also you might find the posting [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/259376/Using-AJAX-AutoCompleteExtender-for-autosuggest) useful.

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
runat="server" 
ID="autoComplete1" 
TargetControlID="myTextBox"
ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
CompletionInterval="1000"
EnableCaching="true"
CompletionSetCount="20" 
CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
    <Animations>
        <OnShow> ... </OnShow>
        <OnHide> ... </OnHide>
    </Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```